# Text-center jump on scroller appear

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am trying to make the logo text in center. The `.main` div could be long and can show scroller (Windows) on house hover.

However, the **Text Logo** jumps / changes its position when mouse hover and the scroller appear. How to prevent that? To test, please shrink the browser height to see scroller in effect.

**Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/tppzm/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="logo">
        Logo Text
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    background: gray;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.main:hover {
    overflow: auto;
}

.logo {
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

**Requirements**:

- I like to center `.logo` without changing its position even with scroller.
- Prefer not to use JS to adjust position in this case and no hardcode position.

**UPDATE 1:**

There are two alternatives that I don't like so much:

1. `position:absolute` will work but also messed up my other stuffs
2. `width:180px` on the `.logo` will fix it but again, it's hard code too although you can argue that `200px` was also hardcoded

Comment: which browser you find this issue ?

Comment: I am wondering `position:absolute` is the only way?? Again, not ideal as it messed up other stuffs

Comment: @HP. The second solution i provided was the most elegant you would find. Anyways your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.logo` is not getting sufficient width to understand its positioning on hover, so to make it realize that it should stay at center, it should inherit the width of its parent.

**For Instance,**

```
.logo {
    text-align: center;
    width: inherit;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tppzm/6/)**

Hope this helps.

***PS:** If you want to change the overflow (Scroll) of `.main:hover`, you can set it accordingly to your needs by making it visible or hidden on `overflow-x` or `overflow-y`*

Comment: Yes indeed, but you had mentioned `.main:hover {overflow: auto;}`, so it was obvious that you are prepared to make it scroll either ways, but you can hide on hover by `overflow-x:hidden;` or `overflow-y: auto;` - @HP.

Answer (score 1):

You will always have this issue because you are using the following code.

```
.logo {
   text-align: center; 

}
```

The width of your main class is 200px, but when the scroller comes into play the width changes to 180 px and hence the positioning of the logo div changes automatically to center it. If you want a fixed logo then you can do something like this

```
.logo {
/*   text-align: center; */
    margin-left:50px;    
}
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tppzm/3/)

```
OR
```

ALTERNATE SOLUTION

On hover of main change the width to 220px so that it compensates for width of the scroller.

[ALTERNATE SOLUTION FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/tppzm/4/)

```
.main:hover {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 220px;
}
```

Comment: it is working for fixed width but for variable width it seems to be not good. because we want align logo exactly in center

Comment: I think besides the 2 solutions i provided nothing else can be done using plain CSS.

Comment: [It can be done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922313/text-center-jump-on-scroller-appear/19922654#19922654) - @MarsOne